# PayPal REST API - Get Sale by Transaction ID - The requested resource ID was not found (404)

Tags: paypal

I am essentially trying to get the details of any transaction ID in my PayPal account to authenticate users I am migrating to a new authentication system.

I am using the PayPal Rest API so: http://puu.sh/gdb3T/461dde2928.png and yes I have checked everything is fine, it is infact set to live with the correct id / secret.

Comment: Was the transaction ID generated from a Classic payment?  The REST API will only return resources for payments made using the REST API.  If the payment was made using the REST API, what API call are you making to get the resource? (I can't view the link you posted due to firewall restrictions)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly an answer to this specific question, but I have simply fixed it by using PayPal's classic API in order to get the job done.

Kind of strange the rest API doesn't let me do this.

Comment: Yup, this is a PayPal suckage. The classic APIs (and the web interfaces) share a set of transaction IDs and behaviors; everything interchanges properly. Unfortunately the next two API systems (Adaptive and REST) were built as layers atop the underlying system; these newer layers only see "their own" transactions, and the REST layer even implemented its own transaction ID scheme which thorougly breaks backward compatibility. So these newer API layers can't touch/display/whatever transactions other than the ones created through those same layers.

Comment: Just for reference, the PayPal SDK team is [tracking](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/244#issuecomment-73744874) [this](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/issues/3#issuecomment-75555065) [feedback](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/issues/78) as we agree it's something that should be implemented.  It's a major pain point for existing merchants who want to upgrade their PayPal integrations to use the REST services but can't because it means they lose visibility on non-REST transactions.

Comment: @JasonZ: I'm casting my vote for the ability to search for and locate ANY transaction via the REST API (and the .NET SDK), not just those created by an API. In other words, the REST API (and the .NET SDK) should be able to locate transactions that were created manually via the website user interface. A mere list of API-created transactions (by any API) is simply not sufficient—manually-created transactions should be included as well. This is a very serious issue. I haven't seen discussion regarding the problem that's dated newer than over a year ago, so I hope attention to it hasn't waned.

Comment: I was having the same issue on iOS:      message = "Requested resource ID was not found.";
    name = "INVALID_RESOURCE_ID";  However, I just realized that I was using the sandbox urls for verification:  "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/"  and the oauth2 paypal token:  "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token".  I took out the sandbox parts of the urls, and I am trying it now.